# Angular 8: duplica datos cuando vuelvo a la misma ruta

Tags: angular

tengo un problema con angular que no logro comprender. tengo una aplicacion hecho con angular 8 y tengo un componente en `localhost:4200/inicio` y tengo otro componente en `localhost:4200/tabla` resulta que cuando navego entre los dos componentes usando

```
<a mat-list-item routerLink="/inicio"></a>
<a mat-list-item routerLink="/tabla"></a>
```

me duplica la información.

muestro cantidad de registro que realmente tiene la tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando navego de nuevo a /inicio y despues a /tabla (sin recargar el navegador)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al recargar el navegador me vuelve a la cantidad de registros originales (13), lo único que supongo que pasa es que guarda datos en el caché pero no se como areglar ese problema ni por donde comenzar arreglar, si me pueden aunque sea que pasa se lo agradecería mucho porque me urge areglar ese problema

NOTA: la información la leo en `TablaComponent`

```
   import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
   import { RouterLinkActive, Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
   import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
   import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';

   export interface PeriodicElement {
     id_vehiculo: number;
     nombre: string;
     modelo: string;
     configuracion: string;
   }

   // definimos el array de elementos
   const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [];

   export class TablaComponent { 


     disp = {
       id_vehiculo: 0,
       nombre: '',
       modelo: '',
       configuracion: ''
     };

     // inicializamos la tabla
     dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);

     constructor() {
       this.obtenerInfo();
     }

     obtenerInfo() {
       this.http.get('url').subscribe((data) => {
          // aqui lleno la informacion de la tabla
          this.dataSource.data.push(...data);
       });  
     }
   }
```

Comment: crear un array de datos con la repuesta?

Comment: Es muy probable que el código que no está funcionando bien es precisamente el código que no estás mostrando `// aqui lleno la informacion de la tabla`. Para poder recibir ayuda tienes que mostrar algo de codigo que los demas puedan ejecutar y reproducir el error.

Comment: Ya agregué parte del código donde lleno la tabla del componente `mat-table`, esperando algun comentario del por qué ese comportamiento de angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error que mantienes es que siempre estas dando push a los items, con los mismos datos en tu funcion **obtenerInfo**, por lo tanto se estan duplicando lo que puedes hacer es vaciar el array antes de obtener los datos.

```
obtenerInfo() {
       this.http.get('url').subscribe((data) => {
          this.dataSource.data = [] //vacias los datos
          // llenas la informacion de la tabla
          this.dataSource.data.push(...data);
       });  
     }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, en ningún momento me puse a pensar en eso, pensé que era un problema de angular, se resolvió el problema compañero.